# Spirit with a vengeance, questions its name

Tags: riddle

Here is a riddle from my native language "Telugu", just wanted to share it because there is no English version of it here.

```
I am black and I am doing great.
You woke me up from deep sleep, used all kinds of sorcery and turned me red,
just because you had the power to do it.
Now I lost my soul and only my white self is left.
I curse your future generations to suffer.
Who am I?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you

> coal

Because:

> Coal is black. Coal has had a deep sleep, being created from pressure over a long time. We then ignite it, using sorcery, turning it red, just because we want the power that is stored in it. After it is burnt, only gray/white ashes remain. The burning of coal is bad for the environment, so it is cursing our future.